# Breadcrumb separator click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I display hierarchical data with the bootstrap breadcrumb. Clicking the separator `>` I want to display a dropdown list of the siblings, similar with windows explorer when we click the folders in the path. Clicking the arrow after `Intenet Explorer' we see the sub folders

[image]

```css
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: ">";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Parent</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Subitem1</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

For the breadcrumb `Parent > Item1 > Subitem1` if I click the separator between `Parent` and `Item1` I want a dropdown showing `Item1`(active) `Item2` and `Item3`

```
Parent
   Item1
     Subitem1
     Subitem2
   Item2
   Item3
```

Not sure how to make the separator a dropdown

Comment: Not sure to get what you want ? Do you want a simple dropdown ? If yes this might help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use build-in separation because they are based on CSS ::before. You need them in HTML to make them clickable.

All you need to do is to put dropdown as separator. Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/

```css
.breadcrumb-item + .breadcrumb-item::before {
    display: none !important;
}

.breadcrumb .dropdown.show .arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Parent</a> > </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a href="#">Item1</a>
      <div class="dropdown d-inline">
        <a class="d-inline-block arrow" href="javascript:" data-toggle="dropdown">
          >
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Subitem1</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```